# User permissions to edit items but not site

Tags: permissions, contribute

What I want to do is simply give the users full permission when it comes to **adding and editing documents**.

**I do not want them to be able to edit the site itself.** The problem seems to be that when editing the specific permissions the option that gives users permission to edit documents also includes editing the site.

Comment: Contribute permission shouldn't let them edit site, did you try giving Contribute level of access to your users? Are you using SharePoint/AD groups?

Comment: Hi. I am currenty using groups, yes. I don't know if i am on contribute since my sharepoint is in swedish. Althought it is the permission level that is above read and below design so i guesse it shoudl be it. If i use the read option wich is just below it wont let the users edit the documents on the site, that is an important feauture. By editing the site i mean clicking the little pen top right corner and changing the look of the front page.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission Levels, this will take you to the page with the settings for the different permission levels. Assuming they come up in the same order, Contribute is the 4th item down and has a description "Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.". Edit is the 3rd item and has the description "Can add, edit and delete lists; can view, add, update and delete list items and documents." Obviously your descriptions will be in Swedish but hopefully this might help you identify which one "Participate" relates to.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. Somehow my 4th is read. Thought, i just activated the ''community site'' thing in site settings and it sort of soloved itself. So yes problem soloved! Thanks for the commintment thought, will give a thumb up!

Comment: Excellent, good to hear you have got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **check properly the permissions you are giving** to the users: you better use SP groups. Use the '**share**' icon and check the type of permission you are giving clicking on '**show options**': there you have to give **contribute** or **edit** permissions. If you don't give full control, they won't be able to change anything in the site.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. My sharepoint is in swedish and it wont let me change to english, sadly. I currently have my users in my users in a big group wich has the, directly translated, participate level of permission. It's the one between design and read. Everything is fine except for the fact that they can click the little pen in top right corner and edit the front pages look. If i demote them to read they can not edit documents on the site.

Comment: check this http://sharepointsv.blogspot.ch/2010/08/auktorisering-behorigheter-i-praktiken.html with the edit command you say thay can modify that page, not necessarly the whole site. If you want them to be able to create new pages or modify pages, you have to use 'edit' or 'contribute' levels. If you mean you want them only to be able to add a text to a page but not to edit, the situation is different

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help.I just activated the ''community site'' thing in site settings and it sort of soloved itself. Thanks for the commintment thought, will give a thumb up!

Comment: So please upvote...

Comment: Hi, im sorry. I can not do that at the moment, it says i need more rep. Will upvote as soon as i get it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them Contribute permissions, not Edit. The Contribute permission level is specifically designed for users to view, add, update, and delete list items and documents within libraries. Edit gives the next level up of permissions to enable the user to add, edit and delete lists and libraries. Stick with Contribute and all will be fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. My sharepoint is in swedish and it wont let me change to english, sadly. So i am currently using the directly translated; Participate, level. It's between read and design so i guesse that should be the contribute one. The problem is they can still edit stuff on the page if they click the pen in the top right corner. Wich disappears if i use the read option, thought on read they can not edit documents on the site.

Comment: Erik, if all you want the users to go is work on a few document libraries then you could give them Read access on the site level and Contribute on the Document library.